# Wildcard search in Elasticsearch - Python

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

My code :

```
search_parm ={
    "query": {
        "match" : { "message" : "*error*" }
    }
res = es.search(index='indice_1', body=search_parm)
result = res['hits']['hits']
print(result)
```

I am trying to get the messages which has the text 'error' in it.
The search parameter fetches the below result:

```
'message': 'Error handling attributes invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)'
```

But, the below value is not fetched :

```
'message': 'Sent message on queue: documentprocessing_error'
```

Mapping of message field :

```
  "message" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
```

Please let me know how I have to edit the search parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my search parameter to

```
search_parm1 = {"query": {"wildcard": {"message": { "value": "*error*","boost": 1.0,"rewrite": "constant_score"}}}}
```

Working as expected. Thanks.